# how to split a English sentence without any delimeter in php

Tags: php, twitter, hashtag, sentence

i want to split twitter hash tags without any delimiter using php

e.g:

```
#HashTags       to 1-Hash 2- Tags
#MoveOver    1- Move    2- Over
#PhpIsaHighLevelLanguage   to 1- Php   2- is   3- a   4- high   5- level   6- language
```

how to did it?

Comment: Use a regexp to split on capital letters using something like `(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regexp to split on capital letters using something like:

```
$data = 'PhpIsaHighLevelLanguage';
$results = array_filter(
    preg_split('/(?=[A-Z]+[^A-Z]?)/', $data)
);
var_dump($results);
```

But the `Isa` in `PhpIsaHighLevelLanguage` needs to be `IsA` to split correctly into two words without additional language intelligence

Comment: thanks for your reply.... suppose sentence is in lower or mixed case as on twitter hashtags..... so what will be then?

Comment: If there's no consistent capitalisation that you can use, then you need to start learning about how to program natural language or use a dictionary in order to identify words.... and hope that you never need to split phrases like `#expertsexchange` or `#penisland` or `#therapistfinder` or `#gotahoe` or `#molestationnursery`